# Clip UIView to UIIimage(UIImageView) using .png

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a few UIImage's. All of them are in .png format. I need to clip another Image or UIView to the opaque part of the UIImage. Some of the images have some transparency around the outside edges. If I use the clipsToBounds it will only clip to the frame of the UIImageView not the actual image. If I make the line to be clipped the same height it will look fine in the center but I need to position the line off center to the right or left at times. Please see the photo for a better explanation. I've tried a few methods using Core Gaphics, but alas, I have not found the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `CALayer`'s `mask` property.
It allows you to define

> An optional layer whose alpha channel is used as a mask to select
>   between the layer's background and the result of compositing the
>   layer's contents with its filtered background.

To mask a view to a .png, set the mask layer's `contents` to a `CGImageRef`.

Remember to import the `QuartzCore` framework though! ;)
[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a Look at CALayer's mask property. You can set a layer which's opacity will be used as alpha information for the layer of the view (yourUIImageView.layer.mask).

E.g. you can use CAGradientLayer to add an alpha gradient to your view, or use the layer of your other UIImageview if it has an alpha channel.

Edit: Jenox was faster and provided more info, so his answer should be marked as correct.